# Pandas Read CSV with dates as DD-MMM-YY

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have a data set that looks as follows in a CSV file:

```
Date          Sample
01-AUG-09     Sample 1
02-Aug-09     Sample 2
etc...
```

When I use Pandas, I read in the file with the following code:

```
in_file = pd.read_csv('File Name.csv', parse_dates = True)
```

However, it is not recognizing the date column properly. Does anybody know if the Pandas date parser can recognize dates that are in DD-MMM-YY format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me

I suspect yours is probably much simpler to parse because they are many tab separated? (I did an exact width parsing which is not trivial)

```
In [41]: df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(data),widths=[9,13],parse_dates=True,index_col=0,names=['sample'],header=None,skiprows=1)

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
              sample
2009-08-01  Sample 1
2009-08-02  Sample 2
```

Tab separated is much simpler

```
In [43]: data2 = """Data\tSample\n01-AUG-09\tSample 1\n02-Aug-09\tSample 2\n"""

In [44]: read_csv(StringIO(data2),sep='\t',parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
Out[44]: 
              Sample
Data                
2009-08-01  Sample 1
2009-08-02  Sample 2
```